# Unity3d 2017 trail renderer behaving weird

Tags: unity, car, trail-renderer

Please see the screenshot I attached, I am trying to make skid marks using trail renderer, but one side of trail is going upwards just after it renders, it was working fine Unity 5.4, but when I upgraded it to 2017, it is behaving like this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to put a script on the trail gameobject, and in `start()` just write:

```
myTrails = gameObject.GetComponent<TrailRenderer>(); 
myTrails.Clear();
```

That's it. Trails will start fresh when they appear!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this happens because your object starting point is `(0,0,0)` (world origin), hence the trail is being rendered from that position too.

You should create your object to a given position rather that creating it at the origin and then moving it to another place: this way the origin will not count as a valid coordinate for trail rendering.

If that doesn't work, you can use a different approach: when the object is created, its trail has a `Time` value equal to 0. Next step, you can set `Time` to a desired value, for the very first coordinate (world origin) will not count as timing out in respect of the `Time` value, but the next will because the timer will be greater than 0.

Comment: please check another screen shot for trail renderer settings, can u suggest some values?

Comment: `Time` is expressed in seconds, you can tweak is value to find the best effect to fit your game.

Comment: Did this answer help you? If so, you may mark it as accepted.